# Draft.js: How to build ContentBlock with type atomic?

Tags: draftjs

I define a blockRendererFn callback to render a block with my own defined component. But How can I build the editor with existing content? Constructor of ContentBlock has no option to accept my component

Answer (score 6):

> Constructor of ContentBlock has no option to accept my component

You can pass your custom component name to `type` property of `ContentBlock` configuration object.
For example, we have a custom component with `MyCustomBlock` name. And we have an array of strings, that you want to wrap in the custom component and show as an existing content of the editor. Create an array of `ContentBlock`s this way:

```
const input = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];

const contentBlocksArray = input.map(word => {
  return new ContentBlock({
    key: genKey(),
    type: 'MyCustomBlock',
    characterList: new List(Repeat(CharacterMetadata.create(), word.length)),
    text: word
  });
});
```

and get initial editor state with [`EditorState.createWithContent`](https://draftjs.org/docs/api-reference-editor-state.html#createwithcontent) and [`ContentState.createFromBlockArray`](https://draftjs.org/docs/api-reference-content-state.html#createfromblockarray) methods:

```
this.state = {
  editorState: EditorState.createWithContent(ContentState.createFromBlockArray(contentBlocksArray))
};
```

Look at this working example - http://jsfiddle.net/levsha/vp8utkwv/